# PostList() received an invalid keyword 'template_name'

Tags: django

> as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class

This make no sense to me since template_name is an attribute. I checked for similar questions but couldn't find an indication of where I went wrong with the code. Here is my code.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import PostList

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',
        PostList.as_view(
            template_name='blog/post_list.html'),
        name='blog_post_list'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import View
from .models import Post


class PostList(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(
            request,
            'blog/post_list.html',
            {'post_list': Post.objects.all()})
```

Comment: Even if PostList did accept a template_name argument, you're clearly not using it as you hard code the template name directly in `get`.

Comment: Thank you. Django and Python are new to me but with your help, I was able to apply the solution right away. This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`View`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View) class, doesn't have a `template_name` attribute, you either want to use [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView), or it would make more sense to use a [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

```
class PostList(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'post_list'
    template_name = 'blog/post_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.all()
```

Note: Either way, since you already set the template name in your view, you don't actually need to include it in the call to `as_view` anyway

Comment: Since op needs Post.objects.all() without any customization, we can do:
    model = Post
instead of get_queryset method

Comment: @VinayakKaniyarakkal - I was trying to avoid too many changes to the OP's code so it still has some similarity, but sure, that would work too